# ubuntu doesn't boot with initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic and initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, lvm

I'm not able to boot with initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic and initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic - just drops into a busybox shell with the regular generic message.

I though that was something kernel related and it might be, but two kernels in a row I think it's too much. I have no special configuration other than using LVM.

My fstab looks like:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root               /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=6ac3a683-7119-4db0-b56b-03b0a1926c0e /boot           ext2    defaults          0       2
UUID=CB77-6FD2                            /boot/efi       vfat    defaults          0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1             none            swap    sw                0       0
```

My blkid yields:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="CB77-6FD2" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="6ac3a683-7119-4db0-b56b-03b0a1926c0e" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="5Z8NLG-VdRr-nleK-ww5A-qZuO-oZFZ-9c6DQ7" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="c2e86aae-f4cf-469b-8c50-80cb9006e5f5" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="0705339b-f889-4c1f-a882-a756e95cdc83" TYPE="swap"
```

Everything is find and boots with 3.13.0-34-generic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: _I'm not able to boot_ - What's the actual error message or, if there's none, what do you see in the logs or on the screen?

Comment: Just the regular dropping to a shell.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but it worked:

Add the following modules to `/etc/modules` and `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

```
dm-mod
dm-snapshot
dm-mirror
```

and then install lvm2 or if you already have it installed just run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

again.